# Configure message group ID for FIFO using @SqsListener annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

I am using @SqsListener provided by Spring cloud API in order to consume messages from FIFO queue. I want to consume the messages based on the particular Message Group ID. Not sure on where to configure this setting.

I tried to read AWS spring cloud documentation and did some google but cannot find a answer or example.

My annotation looks like this:

```
@SqsListener(value = orderQueue, deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
```

And I have following SQS config:

```
        public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
            return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync);
        }
```

and using following dependency:

```
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am mainly looking for answer on how to configure @SqsListener to read messages based on Message Group Id.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that even the AWS sdk provides a way to consume messages by their groupId. The groupId is basically just a mechanism to build clusters of messages in Fifo queues. Messages within a cluster are then guaranteed to be delivered in the order they were sent.